# Getting VerifyError when using traits (JRE 1.8.0u25)

Tags: java, groovy, traits

I'm using Groovy to extend some JavaFX classes by the usage of traits.

Unfortunately, implementing a trait at runtime fails, throwing a VerifyError "Stack size too large". I've read that Groovy VerifyErrors are supposed to be caused by a JRE bug in versions <1.8.0u25. But I'm using exactly this latest version.

Further information for my test environments: Groovy embedded non-indy, version 2.3.7 final, error occurs on both Ubuntu (x64, 14.04.1 LTS, running as a VirtualBox Guest) and Windows (x64, 8.1).

Finally, here comes my code:

```
trait DoStuff {
   public void doStuff() {
      println "doing stuff here"
   }
}

class GBorderPane extends javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane {
   public GBorderPane() { 
      super()
   }
}

class TraitsMain {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      GBorderPane g=new GBorderPane().withTraits(DoStuff) // VerifyError here
   }
}
```

The error output is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: GBorderPane1_groovyProxy, method: layoutInArea signature: (Ljavafx/scene/Node;DDDDDLjavafx/geometry/Insets;ZZLjavafx/geometry/HPos;Ljavafx/geometry/VPos;)V) Stack size too large
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1817)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProxyGeneratorAdapter.<init>(ProxyGeneratorAdapter.java:192)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:221)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:189)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:181)
    at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:177)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.withTraits(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:14938)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$619.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at traits.TraitsMain.main(TraitsMain.groovy:10)
```

Any advice on how to handle this would be nice ;)

Comment: I've heard that Oracle fixed this in Java 1.7_u72. As this also affected 1.7_u68 I believe that if they fixed this for Java 7, they will also fix for Java 8. Just wait for their next release or try to get the beta.

Comment: https://twitter.com/kszdev/status/522662104344854529

Comment: The error you get does not actually seem to be related to the Oracle fix. It seems to be a genuine bug in Groovy implementation of traits, because the error says that the bytecode generated did not declare a stack size that was enough for the variables that got pushed into it! I would file a bug in Groovy's JIRA with the exact code you use to get this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY

Comment: I've opened a ticket [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7146) - thanks a lot for your support. I've worked around the problem by injecting the needed methods after object creation, but I want to return to traits later because they seem like a 'cleaner' solution to me.